# SELECT time-stamp based on milliseconds

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, delete-row

I am storing timestamps and some associated user data sent up by android devices in a MySQL table, the structure of which is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `breadcrumbs` (   
  `breadcrumbs_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
  `users_id` int(10) NOT NULL,   
  `timestamp` bigint(20) NOT NULL,   
  `data` text,   
  PRIMARY KEY (`breadcrumbs_id`,`users_id`),   
  KEY `fk_breadcrumbs_users1` (`users_id`)   
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=468792 ;
```

The android devices are sending up the timestamps in milliseconds and is following the UTC time standard to build the timestamps.
I have been trying to remove breadcrumbs older than one month. As MySQL does not have milliseconds format, I have been using the following query:

```
DELETE FROM breadcrumbs WHERE ((`timestamp`)/1000) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 2592000;
```

It takes quite some time to delete the records. Below is the result of running the delete query:

```
/*382,580 rows affected, 0 rows found. Duration for 1 query: 36.894 sec. */
```

My questions are:

1. Am I picking up the breadcrumbs correctly?
2. Can I optimize the `DELETE` query so it runs faster than currently it is.

Comment: I'd rather do the UNIX_TIMESTAMP calculation in your server code; less dependency/logic in the DB laye. And rather than going timestamp/1000 just keep timestamp; the extra division operation takes more time.

Comment: Thanks everybody, for the excellent posts and tips. Well, as for the timestamps, I need to keep the milliseconds version as they are being sent down to other android devices and the android guys want it in the same format it was sent up. The idea of storing it in additional format in another column was really cool!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query logic is correct, but I would suggest not storing the milliseconds format in the first place, and instead, divide by 1000  on `INSERT` (or store both the milliseconds and the plain UNIX timestamp format). Or, store it as a `DATETIME` using `FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp / 1000)` when you `INSERT` it. Then, create an index on the `timestamp` column and deletions should be much faster.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `breadcrumbs` (   
  `breadcrumbs_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
  `users_id` int(10) NOT NULL, 
  `timestamp` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  /* Also consider storing `timestamp` as a DATETIME */
  /* `timestamp` DATETIME NOT NULL, */
  `data` text,   
  PRIMARY KEY (`breadcrumbs_id`,`users_id`),
  KEY `fk_breadcrumbs_users1` (`users_id`),
  /* index on timestamp */
  INDEX `idx_timestamp` (`timestamp`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=468792 ;   

/* Store the timestamp without the milliseconds (or store it both ways in 2 columns) */
INSERT INTO breadcrumbs (`breadcrumbs_id`, `users_id`, `timestamp`, `data`) VALUES (123,123, input_timestamp / 1000, data)
/* Or even better, store it as a MySQL DATETIME */
INSERT INTO breadcrumbs (`breadcrumbs_id`, `users_id`, `timestamp`, `data`) VALUES (123,123, FROM_UNIXTIME(input_timestamp / 1000), data)
```

As an indexed `DATETIME` column, your `DELETE` query would look like:

```
DELETE FROM breadcrumbs WHERE `timestamp` < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH;
```

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**: add an index on `(timestamp)` and test this query, so the index can be used:

```
DELETE FROM breadcrumbs 
WHERE `timestamp` < 1000 * UNIX_TIMESTAMP( NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) ;
```

---

**Option 2**: use @Micahel Berkowsi's approach and store a part of the timestamp, that MySQL can use without convertions.

---

**Option 3**: move to **[MySQL 5.6](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html)** when it is released (it's still in beta testing) or **[MariaDB 5.3 or 5.5](https://kb.askmonty.org/en/microseconds-in-mariadb/)** that support **microsecond accuracy** in datetime and timestamp columns.